# Watch-Os passkey is not appearing

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, watchos

Bluetooth passkey keyboard is not appearing on WatchOs(only Pair button) but working fine on iOS.

I have external camera which is working through Bluetooth connection. Camera has pin on itself for pairing process. The thing is when I'm doing pairing on iOS through the CoreBluetooth and requesting protected characteristics it's working fine.

But as soon as I'm trying to do the same on my Apple Watch (Watch-Os) app it doesn't show Pin dialog, it just show Pair/Dismiss button.

Could anyone explain please why it's happening and is there any possible solution to sync Watch and Camera?

Thank you for any help.